# Jquery File upload: How to set Multiple File Upload Widgets?

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using Jquery File Upload plugin with Django as a backend. Everything worked well until I tried to integrate the [Multiple File Upload Widgets on the same page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page).

**First problem**

First, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to change inspite of the doc. [Here is the original main.js file](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/fileupload/static/js/main.js) mentioned in the page. I'm not jQuery expert and I can't understand here precisely what I need to change.

I'd be so happy to see an example of this main.js rewritten as it should be.

**Second problem**

The whole purpose of having multiple widgets on one page for me, is to display different elements.
That's why, in my backend, the `upload/view/` url became `upload/view/(?P<pk>\d+)/`.

For example, if in one page I want to displays two photos albums containing many photos, I expect my page to call `upload/view/1` and `upload/view/2`

The backend part works well since calling there urls return correct json answer.

But for the ajax part, I don't know what to do. In the `main.js` file, I can see where it should be changed, but don't know how to do it:

```
            $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            //url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            url: '/upload/view/',
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment or delete these part of the code:

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    //url: 'server/php/'
});

// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
);
```

And put this lines, that allow you to set multiple upload widgets based on the `fileupload` class:

```
$('.fileupload').each(function () {
  $(this).fileupload({
    dropZone: $(this)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

based on @Hackerman answer and other brainwister, here is the final working main.js file :

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // cpt will count (0-based) number of fileupload forms in the page
    var cpt = 0;

    $('.fileupload').each(function () {

        $(this).fileupload({
          dropZone: $(this)
        });

        // Load existing files:
        $(this).addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/upload/view/' + $(this).children("input[name='folder_element']").val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('.fileupload')[cpt] // select the right form
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, null, {result: result});
        });

        cpt += 1;

    });

});
```

and the HTML corresponding for 2 forms:

```
<form class="fileupload" method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="folder_element" value="1">
  ...
</form>

<form class="fileupload" method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="folder_element" value="2">
  ...
</form>
```

I'm not jQuery expert, but it seems you need to have a count variable to pass the good context in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (v9.11.1):

The form(s):

```
<form data-id="1" .....
<form data-id="2" .....
```

Make copies of the server (PHP folder in this example) and name them php1 and php2. The main.js file then becomes (keeping more or less true to the original code):

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('.fileupload').each(function () {

        $(this).fileupload({
            dropZone: $(this)
        });

        $(this).fileupload({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: 'server/php'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'/'
        });

        // Load existing files:
        $(this).addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $(this).fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $(this)[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
        });

    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('.fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

});
```